# Is there a relationship between number of units in LSTM cell and "distance" of memory?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I understand the equations governing an LSTM and I have seen [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12964/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-number-of-units-in-the-lstm-cell) which talks about what the number of units of an LSTM means, but I am wondering something different - **is there a relationship between the number of cells in an LSTM and the "distance" of the memory/the amount of "look-back" that the model is capable of?** For example, if my data has a sample rate of 1000 Hz and I have an LSTM with 100 cells, does that mean that my model is only capable of learning relationships between/remembering things from the past 100 ms? Or am I oversimplifying the relationship in my head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no.
Or at least, not directly - but an LSTM layer of a higher latent dimension would have more capacity, and might have more "room" for more complex patterns, including those making use of "distant" memories.

Use of more LSTM layers may also help to learn more complex patterns.

Regarding the 100 cells - 100 time steps part of the question - yes, this is an oversimplification to say the least.